# requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=7545): Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: transactions, web3.py, python, pyethereum, hosting

I created a blockchain app using Ethereum, I downloaded a virtual box. I activated the smart contract on the virtual box and connected it to the Python file on the original device. When the application is executed I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 144, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 83, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 357, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1281, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1327, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1276, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1042, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 980, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 153, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fccac7ca5f8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=7545): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fccac7ca5f8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final.py", line 18, in <module>
    web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/eth.py", line 182, in accounts
    return self.get_accounts()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/module.py", line 44, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str, params, error_formatters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/manager.py", line 154, in request_blocking
    response = self._make_request(method, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/manager.py", line 133, in _make_request
    return request_func(method, params)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 76, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/middleware/gas_price_strategy.py", line 34, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 76, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/middleware/attrdict.py", line 33, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 76, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/middleware/normalize_errors.py", line 25, in middleware
    result = make_request(method, params)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 76, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 76, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/middleware/exception_retry_request.py", line 105, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/providers/rpc.py", line 95, in make_request
    **self.get_request_kwargs()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/_utils/request.py", line 39, in make_post_request
    response = session.post(endpoint_uri, data=data, *args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 567, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 520, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 630, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 508, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=7545): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fccac7ca5f8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

How do I link the smart contract on a computer with the web3.py file on the virtual box??? To do some tests on the Ethereum network

Comment: Is the port in the virtual box exposed?

Comment: How do I know this ??

Comment: where is the answer of this question